# Text and Labels missing in windows control panel

Tags: windows, windows-10, control-panel

I have been facing a weird issue since a month. I couldn't find any solution on the internet which makes me think that the problem is unique to me. The text and labels for the options have disappeared. Only the icons can be seen in the control panel. Although when I place the mouse in the areas where the text is usually present, it shows a kind of selection box but I still can't see the text. It has become invisible.
[image]

I recently updated my windows to windows 10 thinking that the problem will be solved. But the issue is still present. It has become impossible for me to manage the settings. Can someone help me with this?

Control Panel is an important asset. McAfee scan does not show the presence of any virus. I feel this has something to do with the settings. Please Help.

Comment: Does this happen on any other folders? Or only Control Panel? What happens if you hold the shift key while changing view settings?

Comment: @CharlieRB It happens only to the control panel.

Comment: @CharlieRB Also right clicking in the control panel doesn't work and the view is stuck on `tiles`. I am not able to change it.

Comment: You ran a virus scan, but did you run malware scan? If the system is clean, you may want to run `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt to see if it can fix some core system files.

Comment: @CharlieRB Will malwarebytes work?
Because I am not used to the system files.

Comment: The two are not related. Yes, run malwarebytes. Once you have verified the system is clean, run the System File Checker (sfc).

Comment: @CharlieRB I already started running sfc scan.

Comment: @CharlieRB Wouldn't the repair be handled when windows is updated to a newer version? I recently updated windows and the problem persisted.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you upgraded Windows 7 with existing issues, does not mean it will fix all problems. A fresh install might, but no guarantees with an upgrade. Besides, if there is malware attacking the system an upgrade isn't going to fix that.

Comment: Try creating another administrator user account, see if the problem still exists.

Comment: @CoscoTech Yes, I'll do that if sfc /scannow doesn't solve the problem. I have already initiated the process.

Comment: Ok, also try to reset folder options. Search box - "folder options" --> view tab --> reset folders button

Comment: @CharlieRB    sfc/ scannow and resetting folder options didn't work. Moving onto malwarebytes and then finally, a new admin account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved it by myself. Resetting everything back in case of view, folder view etc. didn't work for me.
Finally, as I was wandering around in the `Personalize` settings, I found a `reset to windows recommended` option. I clicked it and everything was back to normal. I feel that some external program must have played with the settings.

Steps:

- Personalize
- Display
- Reset to windows recommended

Finally, I am back in control.

Answer (score 1):

### Reset Win10 Folder Options With a Batch File

**First: Backup Registry**

- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/back-up-registry#1TC=windows-7
- Preferably to a usb stick drive or external drive

**Second: Reset Folder Settings with Batch File**

- Create a batch file - > Open Notepad.exe
- Insert the following code into the blank text file:

`@echo off

:: To reset folder view settings of all folders
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\BagMRU" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /F`

`:: To kill and restart explore
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe`

- Save the file with .bat as the extension and then open the file to run it

Comment: Well, give me some time. Malwarebytes scanning is in progress and it has already detected 12 objects.

Comment: Yup take your time.

Comment: Something simple solved it.

Comment: Ok, you can post your own answer here and mark it as the solution.